# Strange thread behavior when using ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

Below is my code:

```
public class Controller {
    public Button button_submitWork;

    @FXML
    public void handleSubmitWork(ActionEvent event) {
        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1, r -> {
            Thread t = Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(r);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t;
        });//set thread daemon, let all threads terminate when the program is closed.
        Callable<String> callable = new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Executor Service thread");
                StringBuilder stringBuilder_output = new StringBuilder();
                for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                    stringBuilder_output.append(k);
                }
                //Thread.sleep(1000);
                return stringBuilder_output.toString() + "\n";
            }
        };
        Future<String> future = executorService.submit(callable);//Weird line. 
        //This line must be placed inside the "watchThread" to get the result, but why???
        Thread watchThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //<----------Moving to here solve the problem!
                System.out.println("Watch thread");
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !future.isDone()) {
                    try {
                        String result = future.get();
                        System.out.println(result);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        executorService.shutdownNow();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        watchThread.setDaemon(true);
        watchThread.start();
        System.out.println("FX thread");
    }
}
```

The question is that the `System.out.println(result);` inside "watchThread" is never been called. The console output looks like this:

```
Executor Service thread
FX thread
Watch thread
```

But when I move the `Future<String> future =  executorService.submit(callable);` to the inside of run method of "watchThread", the output change to:

```
FX thread
Watch thread
Executor Service thread
01234
```

which is I expected.
I also discovered that if the `call()` method has a longer task, say a `Thread.sleep(1000)`, the output change to the result I expected.

So why is that?

Comment: Besides the answer below, what would you expect from that loop anyway? When Future.get completes (either normally, or via an exception) you exactly get one of your exit conditions in the loop. So there never will be a second round.

Comment: Oh! Yes, you are right. I should remove the while loop. There's no need to put things in a while loop in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread you submit to `executorService` finishes before this line:
`while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !future.isDone()) {` is called so `future.isDone` returns `true` and the `while` loop is not executed.

If you add `Thread.sleep(1000)` then it still runs and `future.isDone` returns false and the `while` loop executes. The same thing happens when you move `Future<String> future =  executorService.submit(callable);` inside `watchThread`.

Comment: Solved, thanks! And I found that I should remove the while loop, it is no use here and even cause a problem.